# Java socket: Can't send proper data

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have a Java TCP server, and an android TCP client. I'm trying to send data from client to server. Sending the data seems to be working fine, but the data that is sent, seems corrupted.

```
        Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();

        System.out.println(clientSentence);
        System.out.println(clientSentence.split(":")[0]);
        if(clientSentence.split(":")[0].equals("packet"))
        {
```

When the server receives the data, the prints show something like this in the console:

```
packet:user:pass
packet
```

Which is as expected. But still my if isn't returning true. As if the "packet" string got from socket, is different from the one I type with keyboard in my source. I can't even copy the text from console. When I copy with mouse and paste it somewhere, it only copies the first character. 
I use the same structures on client side and send the packet with `[DataOutputStream].writeChars(message)`

I don't know if it's a different coding of characters that cause this, or something else. Also it's worth noting that when i capture the text with wireshark, the string is something like ".p.a.c.k.e.t"

Thanks.

EDIT: As asked, client side code is something like this:

```
 Socket clientSocket = new socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
 BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
 DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

 String message = "packet:" + username + ":" + password + "\n";

 outToServer.writeChars(message);
```

It's on an android device.

Comment: If you use readLine() to read then use writeLine() to write.

Comment: We dont' have witeLine for DataOutputStream. But that woudln't matter anyway. All "writeln" does is to add a "\n" to the end, which i do.

Comment: You suggested that writeChars() would send them different. And you can easily add a BufferedWriter to use writeLine(). Just test.

Comment: Isnt there a writeChars(message, "utf-8") ?

Comment: There were no writeln for BufferedWriter either. But I used a write, and the a newLine() and then it worked. I guess it doesn't count "\n" as newline then? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @greenapps There is no `writeLine()` method, and `writeChars()` does not append a line terminator. Could you possibly stop guessing.

Comment: You are reading lines, with `readLine()`, but you aren't sending them, with `writeChars`, which does not append a newline.  If you're using a `Reader` to read you should be using a `writer` to write, and a `BufferedWriter` at that, so you can use `newline()`. But there seems to be another problem here. Post the client code.

Comment: `Could you possibly stop guessin.` @EJP, What bothers you? Consider those as hints to solve the problem. And OP solved before you came in. ;-).

Comment: @EJP There were no other problem. Changing DataOutputStream to BufferedWriter worked. I just did `write()` and then a `newLine()`

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for your help. I don't knwo how i should treat this question? should i close it or answer it?